# Getting information about running tasks from Spring TaskExecutor and TaskScheduler

Tags: spring, asynchronous, scheduler, executor

I've set up a system with a TaskExecutor and Taskscheduler that runs tasks on a cron-like schedule, but also allows tasks to be started on demand.

One particular problem I haven't been able to solve: how can I get information from the executor and scheduler as to which specific task is running right now. Is there a standard way to do this? Should I be looking at a specific subclass or implementation? We are on Spring 3.2 and I tried ThreadPoolTaskExecutor but found it was deprecated. It did have one method 'getActiveCount()' that seemed to go some way towards what I wanted to achieve (though not entirely at all).

Right now, I've put in place a system that takes a snapshot of an ORM object state, waits half a minute and takes another snapshot. A comparison of those two is a pretty foolproof way to know if a task is running on that object.

This, however, doesn't seem like it's the best way to do this (at all!).

Is there a better way?